# Trouble getting array to populate with characters of arguments from loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, arguments

```
function arrayAnalyzer(numbers){ 
var array = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
    array.push(arguments.charAt(i)); 
  }
  console.log(array); 
} 

arrayAnalyzer(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3);
```

its giving me "arguments.charAt" is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push `arguments[i]`:

```js
function arrayAnalyzer(numbers) {
  var array = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
    array.push(arguments[i]); 
  }
  console.log(array); 
} 

arrayAnalyzer(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3);
```

Also you could do the same in shorter way:

```js
function arrayAnalyzer(numbers) {
  // Since arguments is Array-like object let's convert it to array:
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
} 

console.log(arrayAnalyzer(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3));
```

By the way `charAt` is a [method of String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) and `arguments` is an [Array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and of course is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tweaks will make it work:

```
function arrayAnalyzer(numbers){ 
var array = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    array.push(numbers[i]); 
  }
  console.log(array); 
} 

arrayAnalyzer([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3]);
```

Comment: So you propose to pass an array and just return its copy. I think Darien just wants to work with a variable number of arguments.